# Rotation matrix addition

Tags: python, game-engine, matrix

I suck at programming but am trying to rotate an object a specific way. The line 
`own.localOrientation=mathutils.Matrix(x, y, z)` is giving me an error:

`TypeError: Matrix(): expects no args or a single arg containing 2-4 numeric sequences`

The most likely problem is I'm formatting the matrix wrong when I go to add it but the error isn't really helping me figure out exactly what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Euler rotation as a matrix**

Would imagine that what you want for `x, y, z` is an [`Euler`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Euler) rotation.

The [`KX_GameObject.localOrientation`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=localorientation#bge.types.KX_GameObject.localOrientation) expects a 3x3 matrix, an `Euler` or a `Quaternion`.

```
euler_rotation = mathutils.Euler((x, y, z), 'XYZ') # XYZ is default
# 3 x 3 rotation matrix
R = euler_rotation.to_matrix()
```

this is the equivalent of

```
Rx = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(x, 3, 'X')
Ry = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(y, 3, 'Y')
Rz = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(z, 3, 'Z')
R = Rz * Ry * Rx # ( XYZ order)
```

Can either set your local orientation to this matrix, or to rotate by it

```
own.localOrientation = R * own.localOrientation
```

remember all rotations need to be in radians. `x = math.radians(45)`

Putting it together in game engine, the following in a text block named `rot.py`

```
from mathutils import Euler
from math import radians
x = y = z = radians(5)
R = Euler((x, y, z)).to_matrix()

def main(cont):
    own = cont.owner
    # color vector xyzw  ~ rgba
    own.localOrientation = R * own.localOrientation
```

Assign to the left mouse click. Now on every click the owner is rotated 5 degrees on each axis each click

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the 'XYZ' portion. Says invalid syntax. Removing it then says mathutils.Euler() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: @Scalia Notice it's `Euler( (x, y, z) )` not `Euler(x, y, z)` The first has one argument the tuple `(x, y, z)` "and is right" the second three, `x`, `y` and `z`  "wrong"  `Euler((x, y, z), 'XYZ')` has two arguments and is "right"

Comment: R = Rz @ Ry @ Rx # ( XYZ order)  #inversed order

Comment: Thankyou edited.

Answer (score 1):

To create a rotation matrix with angle try:

```
mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(radians(90.0), 4, 'X')
```

as mentioned in the [Blender API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html)

Comment: ValueError: Matrix.Rotation(): can only return a 2x2 3x3 or 4x4 matrix

Comment: What is the code belonging to this error?